# java how to add subclass objects to an ArrayList in another class

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to learn how to use inheritance for a class project, making a game. They have pretty silly names, sorry. I have an abstract class Cabbages, and a subclass GoodCabbages of it. In the subclass I am basically making an oval.

There is an abstract draw() method in the Cabbages class. I have it implemented in the GoodCabbages subclass like this:

```
public void draw(){
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * (GARDEN_WIDTH - CABBAGE_RADIUS));
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * (GARDEN_HEIGHT - CABBAGE_RADIUS));
    Oval o = new Oval(x, y, CABBAGE_RADIUS, CABBAGE_RADIUS, Color.WHITE, true);
    window.add(o);
}
```

I need add these ovals to an ArrayList in the another class for use later, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
N_GOOD_CABBAGES = 10 //in a separate interface

for(int j = 0; j < N_GOOD_CABBAGES; j++){
    Cabbage good = new Cabbage().draw();
    cabbages.add(j, Cabbage.draw());
}
```

Hopefully this is enough information. Thanks for the help.

Comment: draw returns void. So this code is completely hopeless. Try Cabbage good = new Cabbage(); cabbages.add(good);

Comment: `cabbages.add(j, Cabbage.draw());` is wrong try `cabbages.add(j, good);`

Comment: He wants to store a list of Ovals, not Cabbages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either A) create a method that returns an ArrayList of Ovals, or B) create a public variable in your class.

A)

```
public List<Oval> getOvals() {
    List<Oval> lis = new ArrayList<Oval>();
    //for loop code here
    return lis;
}
```

B)

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<Oval> lis = new ArrayList<Oval>();

    private void myfunc() {
        //add to list here...
    }
}
```

Either way, this really has nothing to do with inheritance. Whether you have good cabbages or bad, the ovals are always of the Oval class.

EDIT: Also, good Java practice: don't use references to ArrayLists (or LinkedLists or HashLists...). Just use the List interface. It makes it more generalized and doesn't cost you anything.

EDIT2: Type problems. List to the compiler dude. Change your code to this:

```
N_GOOD_CABBAGES = 10 //in a separate interface

for(int j = 0; j < N_GOOD_CABBAGES; j++){
    Cabbage good = new Cabbage(); //Cabbage(), not Cabbage().draw()
    cabbages.add(j, good.draw()); //good.draw() not Cabbage.draw(), that's an abstract function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
List<Cabbage> = new ArrayList<Cabbage>(); 
    // an arraylist that holds cabbages (good or otherwise)

N_GOOD_CABBAGES = 10 //in a separate interface

for(int j = 0; j < N_GOOD_CABBAGES; j++){
    Cabbage good = new GoodCabbage(); // make a good cabbage
    cabbages.add(good); // add it to the list
}
```